# Can't figure out why jupyter kernel for scala spark keeps getting interrupted

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I used to have a clean install of the spylon kernel and supposedly after upgrading to a clean 18.04. I am struggling to get the spylon kernel working. The screenshot is basically quitting the spark shell right when it starts as you can see with the "scala> :quit" and  that keeps happening over and over again, infinitely. [image: jupyter kernel for spark scala aka spylon kernel stuck in an infinite "interrupt kernel after restarting loop"]

I tried to do a pip install and also tried conda install the spylon kernel but it's simply not working. Here are the content of the kernel.json file.

```
    {
     "display_name": "sparky",
     "language": "scala",
     "argv": [
      "/home/ops/Documents/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell",
      "{connection_file}"
     ],
     "env": {
      "SPARK_HOME": "/home/ops/Documents/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/"
     }
    }
```

```
ops@ops-XPS-15-9560:~/.ipython/kernels$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python2          /home/ops/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3          /home/ops/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  spylon_kernel    /home/ops/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/spylon_kernel
ops@ops-XPS-15-9560:~/.ipython/kernels$
```

so the installation is also fine and also the spark-shell runs fine on its own

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 0):

Do a full install of anaconda with python 3  and use pip did the trick.